# Merge meshes decreases FPS

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, mesh, frame-rate

I've merged around 2500 meshes (each having their own set of color) but the FPS is lower than if I wouldn't merge.

According to [THIS](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/), merging is the way to go if you want to increase the FPS.

Am I missing something here?

```
var materials = new Array();
var new_geo = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < AllMeshes.length; i++) {
    materials.push(AllMeshes.children[i].material);
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(new_geo, AllMeshes.children[i], i);
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new_geo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, using `MeshFaceMaterial` splits the mesh into separate meshes for each material -- so if you have a separate material for each child mesh, Three.js has to split your combined mesh all the way apart again. As a result, your supposedly merged geometry doesn't actually get sent to the GPU in one batch.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know if it possible to merge all meshes including their respective material so they get sent in one batch?

Or should I ask that in another question?

Comment: Well, you could probably do it if you were able to build one giant texture containing all your materials in the right arrangement to wrap over the originally independent meshes, but there's no built-in way to do that. Consider that if doing so would be an improvement, Three.js would probably do it by default for everything in the scene. Large textures aren't great for the GPU anyway because they may not fit in its on-chip memory.

Comment: Hm alright, guess I need to find another way of doing this.

Comment: If you're just changing colors, you could probably get away with using vertex colors instead of different materials.

Comment: I fixed it with Fragment shader instead ;)
Check it out here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632908/create-a-plane-mesh-with-points-defining-colors